# How to post message on facebook wall with html link?

Tags: android, facebook

In my android app i am using Facebook Api for posting message on his/her wall. Its working fine without any problem. Now i tried to post the message with html link in it. The message get posted on Facebook wall but the html link is not working. It looks like normal text. Here is the message i am trying to post on faceboook wall with the code

```
private String Facebook = "<a href=https://www.facebook.com/>Facebook</a>";

Message = "Hi"+Html.fromHtml(Facebook);
```

Am i doing anything wrong.

**EDIT**

I would like to have like this in facebook wall

Hi,EveryOne [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/) is really nice social website.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: sorry for that.. just updated the question

Comment: is it possible to know the reason for downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet to add html link :

```
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
    try {
            attachment.put("message", "Messages");
            attachment.put("name", "Message");
            attachment.put("href", "http://www.facebook.com");
    } catch (JSONException e) {}
    parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
    facebook.request(parameters);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. In this snippet i would like to know what is facebook in 'facebook.request(parameters)`.. thanks

Comment: Facebook facebook=new Facebook(AppID);

Comment: the thing is i am sending message from other activity to facebook activity

Comment: hi.. It posting the link but what i want it like this [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com).. and message is like this {"href":"http://www.facebook.com/","messages":"message"}do you have idea about that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13930/discussion-between-vinoth-and-venky)

Comment: thanks its working but not like what i am expecting.. anyway thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

```
// put this code in your button click event listener     
facebook = new Facebook("your facebook id");

                    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                    facebook.authorize(this, new String[]
                    { "publish_stream", "offline_access" }, -1,

                    new DialogListener()
                    {
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values)
                        {
                            Log.e("tag", "Values returned by Bundle ====> " + values.toString());
                            fbImageSubmit(facebook, "", "caption", "description", "name", "www.google.com");
                        }

                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error)
                        {

                        }

                        public void onError(DialogError e)
                        {

                        }

                        public void onCancel()
                        {

                        }
                    });

//add method into your class

    private void fbImageSubmit(Facebook fb, String imageurl, String caption, String description, String name, String linkurl)
        {
            if (fb != null)
            {
                if (fb.isSessionValid())
                {
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    //              b.putString("picture", "");
                    b.putString("caption", "");
                    b
                            .putString(
                                    "description",
                                    "test");
                    b.putString("name", "Hi Friends, I am using the your app name app for Android!");
                    b.putString("link", "https://market.android.com/details?id="+this.getApplication().getPackageName().toString());
                    try
                    {
                        String strRet = "";
                        strRet = fb.request("/me/feed", b, "POST");
                        JSONObject json;
                        try
                        {
                            json = Util.parseJson(strRet);
                            if (!json.isNull("id"))
                            {
                                Log.i("Facebook", "Image link submitted.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + strRet);
                            }
                        } catch (FacebookError e)
                        {
                            Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e("Facebook", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer..i edited my question.. i just want like that in facebook wall..